# How to predict future candlestick based on trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Let's assume we have trained a model using **Keras** with more than 90% accuracy.
We have used past data (open price, high, low, close, volume, etc.) with **80-20 train/test split** ratio.
The problem here is that we used the **data which already exists** to predict the data which again already exists.
How can we use this model to predict the future? 
For example, using a trained model to predict red or green candlesticks for the next 4 hours?
I know we can use `model.save` then load the model and finally use `model.predict()` but the problem here is that `model.predict()` **needs some input data for making predictions**.
 Can we use timestamp here as an input (where we don't have the future OHLCV data obviously)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your training data and input data should be in the same format.

For instance if you trained your model with the previous days open, high, etc. data to predict todays data, just input todays data to predict tomorrows.